# Hibernate join query : could not resolve the property

Tags: hibernate

I have two model class UserDetail & TempDataDetail
I have created an object **tempDataDetails** of TempDataDetails in my UserDetails model class and the same **userDetails** of UserDetails  in TempdataDetails.

And my join hql query is "**from UserDetails userDetailsjoin userDetails.TempdataDetails tempDataDetails where userDetails.snrno = tempDataDetails.snrno** " and while executing this query is resulting to an error:
**TempdataDetails could not resolve the property**

I have changed my query to:

And my join hql query is "**from TempdataDetails tempDataDetails join tempDataDetails.UserDetails userDetailswhere tempDataDetails.snrno = userDetails.snrno** " and while executing this query is resulting to an error:
**UserDetails could not resolve the property**

And my getter() setter() are:

---

```
public class UserDetails{

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private TempDataDetails tempDataDetails;

    public TempDataDetails getTempDataDetails() {
        return tempDataDetails;
    }

    public void setTempDataDetails(TempDataDetails tempDataDetails) {
        this.tempDataDetails = tempDataDetails;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TempDataDetails{

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tempDataDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private UserDetails userDetails;

    public UserDetails getUserDetails() {
        return userDetails;
    }

    public void setUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails) {
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is case-sensitive. The fields are named `tempDataDetails` and `userDetails`, not `TempdataDetails` and `UserDetails`.

Comment: please send us with a query JB

Comment: Is it so hard to replace the bad field names in your existing queries by the correct ones?

Comment: here is my query:
SELECT * FROM UserDetails userDetails join userDetails.TempDataDetails tempDataDetails WHERE userDetails.snrNo = tempDataDetails.snrNo

Comment: So, in this query, replace `userDetails.TempDataDetails` by `userDetails.tempDataDetails`.

Comment: Thank you Sir...
after replacing that My query is not showing any error but also not accessing the data from the database...